# how to synchronize two div on scroll of first div horizontal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs, one is header other is body. Width of both div are different. I want to synchronize the header on scroll of body horizontal.  I am using this script:

```
<div class="table-header " > 
    <div class="dep">Dep #</div> 
    <div class="_lName">Last Name</div> 
    <div class="_fName">First Name</div> 
</div> 
<div class="table-body"> 
    <div class="dep">Dep #</div> 
    <div class="_lName">Last Name</div> 
    <div class="_fName">First Name</div> 
</div>



 $(".table-body", that.target).on("scroll", function(event){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $("#headerDiv").scrollLeft( $(".table-body").scrollLeft()*1.27);
      },500);
    });
```

and the CSS is

```
.table-header {
    width: 798px !important;
     overflow : hidden;
}
.table-body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 632px !important;
    height: 50px !important;
}
```

But it is not synchronized. How can I fix it?

Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/psczne5e/

Comment: share your HTML too pls

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "synchronized"?

Comment: <div class="table-header " >
        <div class="dep">Dep #</div>
        <div class="_lName">Last Name</div>
        <div class="_fName">First Name</div>
</div>
<div class="table-body">
     <div class="dep">Dep #</div>
        <div class="_lName">Last Name</div>
        <div class="_fName">First Name</div>
    </div>

Comment: I want when table-body scroll the header is also scroll with same distance. currently it is not happing .

Comment: I think the header is in the body so if the body scroll the header must scroll too. Put them in the same div instead it will works.

Comment: @Stages    I can not do this because if I do so when the contents are more then vertical scroll bar hides the header .

Answer (score 0):

Okay here what I propose.
1. Put the **header** in the **body** (btw its normal).
2. Edit your css like this :

```
header{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
height:100px;
min-height:100px;
width:100%;
min-width:800px;
}
```

WIth no Css for overfolw, it will be the same as your body, so if you want y and x scroll say it in your body Css.
The x scroll will now be the same and the body would go behind the header for y scroll. (if not give a z-index to your header)
This must do what you want.